# VGA monitor works with Windows but not with Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, nvidia, windows, monitor

I have a dual boot PC with a NVIDIA 610 graphics card, usually connected to a HDMI monitor. Testing a free-to-me VGA monitor works with both monitors, but not with the VGA only on Ubuntu 20.04. VGA works fine on Windows though.

Comment: We're going to need more info about the hardware. What monitor is it? Are you using a VGA port on your device or an (active) HDMI to VGA adapter to connect your monitor? Is your setup `VGA on PC -> Monitor` or is it more complex like `HDMI on PC -> Active VGA converter -> Monitor`?

Comment: What graphics device/s do you have, what drivers are you using?  Ubuntu Settings -> About will give you basic info. And I suggest you update your question with the results of the following with the monitor connected: `xrandr` and also `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`

Comment: it was a driver problem, nVidia 610 now using prop driver 390 and all is well. Thaks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

Generally installing the proprietary Nvidia graphics driver automatically works for most systems with Nvidia graphics cards.

```
sudo apt update  
sudo ubuntu-drivers install     
sudo reboot
```

In your case you have old hardware, so start from the bottom with the oldest proprietary Nvidia graphics driver which is nvidia-driver-390 in Ubuntu 20.04. If that doesn't work, work your way up by uninstalling the old Nvidia graphics driver version with `sudo apt remove '^nvidia' && sudo reboot` and installing a newer Nvidia graphics driver version.

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390    
sudo reboot
```